# Is 'Today is gone good' correct?

Tags: sentence-structure

Is the below sentence correct?

"Today is gone good"

people are saying that we have to use either "gone for good" or "gone well".

Please clarify the doubt with good explanation :)

Comment: Google Books [the below sentence is](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+below+sentence+is%22):2 hits, [the sentence below is](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+sentence+below+is%22):2030 hits. I realise this is a bit of a hassle for learners, since *the **above sentence** is* is almost four times more common than *the **sentence above** is*, but if you want to avoid using "marked" forms you just have to get used to this one. So I'll edit the question text.

Comment: Fair enough. It's your post, so if you want to revert my edit that's your prerogative. (In the circumstances though, I trust the mods won't delete my above comment! :)

Comment: I assume you're taking an "Indian English" perspective on this usage point. Even without the clue from your username, I'd interpret your phrasing as evidence that you're probably Indian - not *necessarily* a "non-native Anglophone, since there are at least some native Anglophones in India.

Comment: But I would say that [the trend](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+sentence+above+is%2Cthe+above+sentence+is%2Cthe+sentence+below+is%2Cthe+below+sentence+is&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20sentence%20above%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20above%20sentence%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20sentence%20below%20is%3B%2Cc0) is towards putting the adjective *after* the noun, so I doubt your version will prevail in the long run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the sentence is not correct.  Possible correct sentences are

> Today is gone for good

or

> Today has gone well

or possibly

> Today is going well

but they mean completely different things.

The first one ("Today is gone for good") is in the simple present, and says something about the current state of today; specifically, that it is **gone for good**.  ["For good" is an idiom that means "permanently" or "forever".](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/for+good) So the sentence is saying that today is gone forever.

The second one ("Today has gone well") is in the present perfect and says that today, up until this time, has progressed in a satisfactory way.

The third one ("Today is going well") is in the present progressive and means that this day, right now, is currently progressed in a satisfactory way.

If you want to talk about the satisfactoriness of the day with the verb *to go*, you have to use *well* and not *good*, because *well* is an adverb that modifies the verb *to go*, and *good* is an adjective.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.Why shouldn't we use "gone good"?

Comment: @Krishna: You shouldn't say *Today has gone good* for the same reason you should avoid *The boy done good.* These usages do occur, but they're generally considered substandard/uneducated.

Comment: Nevertheless, *many* native speakers use *good* as an adverb and would say *Today has gone good*, just like **even more native speakers** say *I'm doing good*, with *good* as an adverb describing *doing*, not as an adjective describing *I*. This is for the OP's knowledge. Although I also would encourage learners to use *sentence below*.